# RestFB : Retrieving Attachments present in private messages

Tags: facebook, restfb

I need to retrieve the attachments present as a part of private messgaes posted to my account in Facebook. I am using restfb api to do the same but am getting only the text message as a response, no link to the attachments. Is there a way to get the links or retrieve the attachments?

I am using restfb version 1.6.9.

Steps to reproduce this are

1. Create a private message in Facebook with photo attached.
2. Access Inbox of the account using graph API.
3. web service response returns just content and sender details